# How to change part of numpy array without reshaping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the the following array

```
import numpy as np
import CustomClass

# Total = 24
height = 4
width  = 6
a = np.empty((height, width), dtype=object)

for row in range(self.height):
    for col in range(self.width):
        self.a[row, col] = CustomClass()
```

I would like to change the attribute for part of the array (filled with my custom class).
For example, I would like to change 12 elements starting from element[0,0], then from row to row. Ideally, I would do something comparable to

```
change=11
for i in range(change):
   a[i].value=True
```

The result would be something like the following (0: unchanged, x: changed)

```
x x x x x x 
x x x x x 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The problem with my array is that I first need to flatten it before I could do something like this. Or I should calculate how many columns and rows I before I can index the array itself. Is there a numpy function such that I can just iteratre over the array element by element (row by row).

I hope my explanation is clear?

Comment: If your numpy is 2-d, then you can calculate the mod of (number of rows) and also columns to do that. But any specific reason not to use flatten and reshape?

Comment: Reshaping or flattening the array doesnt change it in memory, it only changes the metadata. You can flatten and reshape as much as you like without performance hits.

Comment: Perforamance and _trying to learn new functions_ were the reason to ask this question. But It seems that flatten and reshape is enough. However, I still need to use a for loop to change te values. Any suggestions to do this differently or can I not avoid the for loop

Comment: After you flatten you can use slicing like `full_array[0:change] = new_values` as long as the shapes match

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however my array consist of objects from which I would like to change the attribute and not replace it with new_values

Comment: you can calculate `x = number % width` , `y  = number // width` and you don't have to flatten it. `arr[y,x] = ...`. OR use variable count and count how many values you changed and then use `break` to exit loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways, but one approach would be to use `np.unravel_index` to get the two-dimensional indices that correspond to the flattened one-dimensional ones. I'll show you how to do this below.

First create your data:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np

height = 4
width  = 6

@dataclass
class myClass:
    value: bool = False
        
data = np.asarray([myClass() for _ in range(height * width)])
data = data.reshape(height, width)
```

Now, make `change` an array of indices that you want to change, rather than the number of elements you want to change:

```
change = np.arange(11)
```

Determine the two-dimensional indices that correspond to those in `change`:

```
rows, columns = np.unravel_index(indices=change, shape=(height, width))
```

And then you can use these indices to iterate over the elements you want to change:

```
for element in data[rows, columns]:
    element.value = True
```

Comment: I like this answer as it learned me something new (`np.ravel_index`) and gets the job done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable to count how many elements was changed and use `break` to exit loops

```
import numpy as np


height = 4
width  = 6
a = np.empty((height, width), dtype=object)
a[:] = '0'

count = 0

for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        count += 1
        a[row, col] = 'x'
        if count == 11:
            break
    if count == 11:
       break
    
print(a)
```

Result:

```
[['x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x']
 ['x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']]
```

---

To make it simpler you can set `count = 11` at start and later substract until you get `0`.

This way you have to set `11` only in one place.

```
import numpy as np

height = 4
width  = 6
a = np.empty((height, width), dtype=object)
a[:] = '0'

count = 11

for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        count -= 1
        a[row, col] = 'x'
        if count == 0:
            break
    if count == 0:
       break
    
print(a)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could also calculate how many full rows you have to change and how many elements you have to change in last row.

```
import numpy as np

height = 4
width  = 6
a = np.empty((height, width), dtype=object)
a[:] = '0'

count = 11

rows = count // width
rest = count % width    

a[:rows] = 'x'
a[rows,:rest] = 'x'

print(a)
```

But this will not work if you want to start in different place then `[0,0]`

Comment: Using nested loops doesn't sound very numpy-esque at all...

Comment: @AKX if it would create rectangle then it could use numpy function for this. But meanwhile I created other method which use more numpy-esque method `a[:rows] = 'x'
a[rows,:rest] = 'x'`

Comment: That seems better already. You can do `rows, rest = divmod(count, width)`, though. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I like the small edited version. Interesting, especially with the divmod. 

However, I'm changing an attribute and not setting an value. Will that work? 
`object.value = True`, is the goal